# VBA Movefrom fails on large file name

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code below.

```
MoveFrom = ActiveCell.Value + "\" + FileList(ndx)
MoveTo = ActiveCell.Value + "\" + ApplyPrefix + " " + RemoveDotsInFileName(FileList(ndx))

Name MoveFrom As MoveTo
```

I get error on Name.
The debugger says,

> "File Not Found"

I look at the watch on MoveFrom.
It is a very large file name.

```
S:\Allied MTRS\Not Scanned\FITTINGS AND FLANGES\_Z_Awaji_Auto_Dev\Temp\TI1 AR 746,747,748,749,750,751,752,753,754,755\Ti16C-0386 It.22 P.O. 92316TI1 Heat 971880 LOT 17555CSG qty 9 17CL-06264.pdf
```

In windows search, I paste this.
The file opens up, so I know it is a valid path/filename.

The only thing is that it is very long.
BUT it is a valid path.

Is renaming restricted because of the length of the MoveFrom  string?

Is there any alternative solution for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Windows has a limitation on the length of the file name.
The problem is not MoveFrom.
The problem is MoveTo.
The target file name is too long.
But the error does not detail that....